# Is it safe to harness move constructor delegation to appropriate copy constructor?

Tags: c++11, copy-constructor, assignment-operator, delegation, move-constructor

To avoid the code duplication I would like to delegate move constructor and move assignment operator to appropriate copy constructor and assignment operator respectively:

```
struct A 
{
  A() {...} //default constructor 
  A(const A& a) {...} //copy constructor
  A(A&& a):A(static_cast<const A&>(a)) //move constructor 
  {
    a.reset();
  } 
  A& operator =(const A& a) //assignment operator
  {
    if (this != &a)
    {
      ...
    }   
    return *this;
  } 
  A& operator =(A&& a) //move assignment operator
  { 
    if (this != &a)
    {
      this->operator=(static_cast<const A&>(a)); 
      a.reset();
    }   
    return *this;
  } 
  void reset() {...}
}
```

Is it a safe technique? 
Are there any pitfalls or caveats here?

Comment: It's legal but one must ask what the point is. If you don't actually want to transfer resources you can jsut leave the move operations undeclared and it will fall back to the copy version. (Code should not rely on the `a.reset` operation)

Comment: @M.M For example, there might be some shared_ptr's in the class, and earlier resetting the source instance may result in an earlier release of resources the shared_ptr's point to.

Comment: An improvement on both designs would be to follow the [rule of zero](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three) and design the class so that the implicitly generated copy/move operations do the right thing